# AngularJS: access to a controller of a template from a directive function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Let's say I have a directive `mydir` applied to the `<body>` element:

`<body data-ng-app="..." id="app" data-ng-controller="AppCtrl" mdir>`.

Inside `<body>` I have an embed `<div>` used for the templating:

```
<div data-ng-view class="main-container"></div>
```

My template has a dedicated controller:

```
<div ng-controller="Controller1Ctrl as ctrl1">...</div>
```

`Controller1Ctrl` has a declared function `foo()`:

```
app.controller("Controller1Ctrl ", ['$scope',
    function ($scope) {
        $scope.foo = function() {
             console.log("I am in foo...");
             ...
        }
    }
]);
```

And I want to invoke this function `foo()` from my directive on some event (let's say `scroll`):

```
app.directive("mydir", function ($document, $route) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            $document.bind('scroll', function (evt) {
                scope.$apply(attrs.scrollable);
                // here!
                scope.$apply("ctrl1.foo()");
                console.log("Just invoked foo()");
            });
        }
    };
});
```

The problem is that `scope.$apply("ctrl1.foo()");` does nothing. No errors in console. I see my "`Just invoked foo()`" log there, but there is no "`I am in foo...`". I suppose that this is because `mydir` directive simply doesn't see `ctrl1` object. While I see the contents of my template on the page (so it is active template).

But how can I achieve it?

And yes, I can not apply `mydir` to the `<div>` inside template. Please don't ask why, simply can not. It should be strictly applied to the `<body>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `$broadcast` to trigger a custom event.

Broadcast an event from your directive

```
scope.$broadcast('myEvent', myVariable);
```

And then listen to that event in your controller

```
$scope.$on('myEvent', (event, myVariable) => {
    // deal with the event
});
```

**Edit**

**Directive**

```
app.directive("mydir", function ($document, $route) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            $document.bind('scroll', function (evt) {
                scope.$apply(attrs.scrollable);
                console.log("Just invoked foo()");

                // Broadcast the event
                scope.$broadcast('myEvent');

            });
        }
    };
});
```

**Controller**

```
app.controller("Controller1Ctrl ", ['$scope',
    function ($scope) {

        $scope.foo = function() {
            console.log("I am in foo...");
            ...
        }

        // listen for the event
        // call $scope.foo() every time the event is received
        $scope.$on('myEvent', (event) => $scope.foo());

    }
]);
```

Comment: Could you please describe it a little bit more detailed. I am newbie in the AngularJS. Where should I place this **broadcast**? Inside the directive function?

Comment: Okay, thank you, that's much closer to what I want to achieve. But now `$scope.foo()` becomes invoked multiple times, while directive's event function only once. I think this is a direct aftermath of the broadcasting. Any ideas how to improve it?

Comment: Well, actually this is an another problem related to how this event is applied to the controller. I am accepting your answer as it answers generally my initial question.

Comment: I am not sure why that might be the case.

Comment: It will be my another question :-)

Answer (score 0):

mdir directive has scope which is parent scope of emded template controller (Controller1Ctrl ). If you want invoke some function in child controller use $broadcast

```
app.directive("mydir", function ($document, $route) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            $document.bind('scroll', function (evt) {
                scope.$apply(attrs.scrollable);
                // here!
                scope.$broadcast("scrolled");
            });
        }
    };
});
```

in Controller1Ctrl listen

```
app.controller("Controller1Ctrl ", ['$scope',
    function ($scope) {
        $scope.foo = function() {
             console.log("I am in foo...");
             ...
        }

        $scope.$on('scrolled', $scope.foo)

    }
]);
```

Comment: Hm... it entails another problem: `$scope.foo()` becomes invoked regardless `scroll`  event it self, just when template becomes rendered...

Comment: I think it should be ` $scope.$on('myEvent', (event) => $scope.foo());` as @VladimirZdenek described